# Oracle SQL efficient query on Partitioned Table: "order by case"

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

I get a table of about 100 billions records partitioned on the key `date_insert`.

**MY_BIG_TABLE**

- id NUMERIC secondary index
- date_insert DATE primary index
- date_fact DATE secondary index
- data BLOB

Input:

- :date_input1
- :date_input2
- :date_input3
- :id

Note: `:date_input1 < :date_input2`

I want

1. `IF date_fact < :date_input_1` the first row ordered by date_fact **DESC**
2. `ELSE IF date_fact < :date_input_2` the first row ordered by date_fact **ASC**
3. `ELSE` the latest

A query prototype should be:

```
SELECT date_insert, date_fact, data (

        SELECT
            date_insert, 
            date_fact,
            CASE 
               WHEN (date_fact < :date_input_1 AND id= :id) : 2
               WHEN (date_fact < :date_input_2 AND id= :id) : 1
               ELSE : 0  
            check,

            CASE 
               WHEN (date_fact < :date_input_1 AND id= :id) : NULL
               WHEN (date_fact < :date_input_2 AND id= :id) : data
               ELSE : NULL  
            data

        FROM MY_BIG_TABLE
        WHERE date_insert > :date_input3   
        order by check, DECODE(check, 1, date_fact) ASC,
                        date_fact DESC 

) WHERE ROWNUM <2
```

I need to do this hard work to avoid too many access to this table.  **Any suggetsion to rebuild completely the query to be simpler and easier?**

Comment: There is no filter for your query? Is that right?

Comment: Yes thank you (the query is a prototype of the real query) ... just edited...sorry

Comment: Well I don't know your requirements but, do you really need the registries with field `data` as NULL because if you don't you can add this part of case statement to your where clause: `and (date_fact < :date_input_2 AND id= :id)` and a Explain plain of your query and the indexes that your table has would be nice to see on your question.

Comment: Yes do not need data in the case 1 and 3...inserted index info.t2u

Comment: ok sorry :date_input1 is ever > :date_input1

Comment: Would likely be easier to conditionally skip evaluating some expressions if you used a stored procedure. If a query for (1) doesn't produce a record, do a query for (2), if that doesn't get a record do the query for (3).

Comment: I cannot use sp in my project....t2u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only looking for one row.  So, do three different subqueries, getting one row each, and then choose the one you want:

```
select date_insert, date_fact, data
from (select date_insert, date_fact, data
      from ((select date_insert, date_fact, data, 2 as check
             from (select date_insert, date_fact,
                          (CASE WHEN (date_fact < :date_input_1 AND id= :id) then NULL
                                WHEN (date_fact < :date_input_2 AND id= :id) then data
                                ELSE NULL
                           end) as data
                   from MY_BIG_TABLE
                   where date_fact < :date_input_1 and date_insert > :date_input3
                   order by date_fact desc
                  ) t
             where rownum = 1
            ) union all
            (select date_insert, date_fact, data, 1 as check
             from (select date_insert, date_fact,
                          (CASE WHEN (date_fact < :date_input_1 AND id= :id) then NULL
                                WHEN (date_fact < :date_input_2 AND id= :id) then data
                                ELSE NULL
                           end) as data
                   from MY_BIG_TABLE
                   where date_fact < :date_input_2 and date_insert > :date_input3
                   order by date_fact asc
                  ) t
             where rownum = 1
            ) union all
            (select date_insert, date_fact, data, 0 as check
             from (select date_insert, date_fact,
                          (CASE WHEN (date_fact < :date_input_1 AND id= :id) then NULL
                                WHEN (date_fact < :date_input_2 AND id= :id) then data
                                ELSE NULL
                           end) as data
                   from MY_BIG_TABLE
                   where date_insert > :date_input3
                   order by date_fact desc
                  ) t
             where rownum = 1
            )
           ) t
      order by check desc
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

Oracle should be smart enough to use the indexes for the subqueries, so this might actually run quite fast.

Comment: it should be a solution but it is more efficient? (+1)

Comment: @venergiac . . . It will be more efficient if the subqueries can use indexes on `date_fact`.  That, in turn, depends on the partitioning and indexing scheme.